# apt-get update fails on Linux Mint Qiana

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I have a Linux Mint 17 (Qiana) machine, which was updated from Linux Mint 14 to 15 to 16 to 17. Currently, apt-get update consistently fails (for several weeks now) with this error message:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://packages.linuxmint.com qiana Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 3EE67F3D0FF405B2 Clement Lefebvre (Linux Mint Package Repository v1) <root@linuxmint.com>

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.linuxmint.com/dists/qiana/Release  

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What's the problem here?

I see that similar questions were closed as duplicates of "how to change my sources list" - this is not what I'm asking, I know how to edit the /etc/apt/sources.list file. If the solution is a specific change to that file, I'd love to know.

For what it's worth, these are the contents of my /etc/apt/sources.list file:

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ qiana main upstream import
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty partner

deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/

# deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu trusty-getdeb apps
# deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu trusty-getdeb games
# deb-src http://packages.mate-desktop.org/repo/ubuntu precise main
```

Comment: check this question answers http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97493/invalid-signatures-when-running-apt-get-update

Comment: also better ask such questions on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is best suited for Unix & Linux SE.

Comment: The existing question suggested here indeed seems relevant, but following the suggested solution didn't solve the problem. SO newbie here, apologies for posting on general SO and not Linux.